# tileserver on Github pages

Tags: leaflet, gis, travis-ci, github-pages

Does anyone know how I can have a tile server hosted on Github pages please. I am making my own pyramid of image tiles (using either pyvips or gdal) but instead of having the tile server locally on my machine, I would like to populate a Github with these tiles and then set my application to fetch the appropriate tiles from that repo.
Any pointers highly appreciated.

Comment: If it is just static content definitely yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes !

You can check https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames that will explain to you the url convention used for serving tiles.

You can then create folders of images on github with the same structure : zoom level / x_coordinates / y_coordinates.png.

I've created and [test github folder](https://github.com/fchabouis/hosting_tiles/).

Here is the [demo page](https://fchabouis.github.io/hosting_tiles/public/demo_control.html)

You can see a tile being displayed, and it is served from github.

Comment: Yes! that is it. Many thanks. I thought initially I had to mess around with travisCI but it was a lot simpler.